# PhP - username and password validation works, however, clearing out other rows

Tags: php, password-protection

I have a html page with the form log-in with username and password. When people enter the correct password, it will take them to the php page with their bills. If the password is incorrect, it will display the error message and then exit the program. I got the log-in function to work. However, it's also effecting my other program. Now every time i try to write something in the item/amount row, it also display the error message and exit the program. I know it has something to do with the $numresult>0 condition. When i took that condition out, my amount/item rows work, but the log-in page also allow blank entry in username/password to log in. Any idea how i can make sure that people have to enter the correct password (not a blank entries) to log in, at the same time, get my item/amount rows in the second page behave as normal? My codes are below. Sorry it's a little long.

```
</head>

<body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: black;" onload=>
<h1>My Bills</h1>
<form method=post>

<?php
//*************************************************
//Connect to Database
//*************************************************


//*************************************************
//Verify password and username
//*************************************************
$password = $_POST['password']; //retrieve variables for password and userId
$userid = $_POST['userid'];

$query  = "SELECT * FROM valid_logon WHERE userid = '$userid' AND
           password='$password'";  //get query from database

$result = mysql_query($query);

$numresults = mysql_num_rows($result); //get row number
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); //get array into variable
$dbuserid = $row['userid'];
$dbpassword = $row['password'];

if ($numresults>0)
{
   if ($userid == $dbuserid && $password == $dbpassword)
   {
       process();
   }   
}else{
   err_msg();
}


//*************************************************
//Error message.
//*************************************************
function err_msg()
{
   print "The username and/or password you have entered are invalid.";
   print "</body>";
   print"</html>";
   exit;
}

//*************************************************
//Write out records with data if they exist.
//*************************************************
function process()
{
  print "<table>";
  print "<tr><th>Item</th><th>Amount</th></tr>";

  $action = $_POST['action'];

  if ($action == 'update')
  {
$write_ctr = 1;

// Delete all rows in the table

$query  = "DELETE FROM n1417_expenses ";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_error()) {
    echo("<br>MySQL Error - Cannot delete from table: ".mysql_error());
    echo("<br>SQL Statement: ".$query);
}


// Loop through table and insert values into the database

while (true)
{
    $item_name = 'item'."$write_ctr";
    $item_value = $_POST[$item_name];

    $amount_name = 'amount'."$write_ctr";
    $amount_value = $_POST[$amount_name];

    if (empty($item_value)) 
    {
        break;
    }

    // Insert an item to the table
    if(!is_numeric($amount_value))
    { 
        print "<font color=red>I'm sorry, amount \"".$amount_value."\" is not a valid number.</font><br>\n";
    }else{

        $query  = "INSERT INTO n1417_expenses (item, amount) 
                  VALUES('".$item_value."','".$amount_value."') ";

        $result = mysql_query($query);
    }

    if (mysql_error()) 
    {
        echo("<br>MySQL Error - Cannot insert a row into table: ".mysql_error());
        echo("<br>SQL Statement: ".$query);
    }

    $write_ctr++;
}

 }



//*************************************************
//Now Select from table and Display
//*************************************************

$err_cnt = 0;
$read_ctr = 1;

$query  = "SELECT item, amount FROM n1417_expenses ";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_error()) {
echo("<br>MySQL Error- Cannot select from table: ".mysql_error());
echo("<br>SQL Statement: ".$query);
}

if (!empty($result))
{
$rowresults = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($rowresults > 0)
{
    for ($read_ctr=1; $read_ctr<=$rowresults; $read_ctr++)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $item_value = $row['item'];
        $item_name = 'item'."$read_ctr";

        $amount_value = $row['amount'];
        $amount_name = 'amount'."$read_ctr";

        print "<tr>";
        print "<td><input type=text name=$item_name value='$item_value'></td>\n";
        print "<td><input type=text name=$amount_name value='$amount_value'></td>\n";
        print "<td>";
        print "</tr>";

        $total_amt = $total_amt + $amount_value;

    }
}
}



//*************************************************
//Now write the blank lines
//*************************************************

for ($i = $read_ctr; $i < $read_ctr + 2; $i++)
{

    $item_name = 'item'."$i";
$amount_name = 'amount'."$i";

print '<tr>';
print "<td><input type=text name=$item_name value=''></td>\n";
print "<td><input type=text name=$amount_name value=''></td>\n";
print '</tr>';
}

print "</table>";
print "<br>Total Bills: $total_amt";

}
?>

<br><input type=submit value=Submit>
<br<br>

<!--  Hidden Action Field -->
<input type=hidden name=action value=update>

</form>
```

Comment: FYI, you are **wide open** to SQL injection, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to do prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: My 2 cents of advice, if you want an answer you should isolate the bit of code that is causing you a headache and only ask a question related to it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question posted, your problem appears to be that the username and password being are checked again when your user submits the form. Because the fields don't exist, the query finds zero rows, triggering your error message.

There are a number of ways of fixing your problem, one way would be to use a [Session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) to remember that a user is logged in. This could be implemented by altering your password check as follows:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || !$_SESSION['logged_in']) 
{

    $password = $_POST['password']; //retrieve variables for password and userId
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM valid_logon WHERE userid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."' AND
               password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'";  //get query from database

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $numresults = mysql_num_rows($result); //get row number
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); //get array into variable
    $dbuserid = $row['userid'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];

    if ($numresults>0)
    {
       if ($userid == $dbuserid && $password == $dbpassword)
       {
           $_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
           process();
       }   
    }else{
       err_msg();
    }
}
```

I've kept the code as similar to the original as possible, but I will echo the comments above on the need to secure your SQL calls. Have a look at using [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) if possible, or at the very least start using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) as above.

Comment: definitely should try and get used to prepared statements when dealing with user submitted variables.  EXTREMELY easy to do, and once you get used to it, you'll never used direct mysql queries again.